# Start another activity error message for editText

Tags: android, kotlin, referenceerror

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity#kotlin

I am at this point on the training and have added the code as advised:

```
    const val EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE"

    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    /** Called when the user taps the Send button */
    fun sendMessage(view: View) {
        val editText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText)
        val message = editText.text.toString()
        val intent = Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity::class.java).apply {
            putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message)
        }
        startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
```

However it doesn't like editText in (R.id.editText).  It is showing in red and pressing alt + enter has not worked on this.  I am only expecting to see an error on DisplayMessageActivity.
I have tried to find a fix to this error online but I can't seem to find anything to help.

Comment: Have you tried manually adding those imports by copy and paste from that tutorial?

Comment: `R.layout.activity_main` in here do you have any edit text with `id` `editText`

Comment: Please share layout xml file.

Comment: @Jems I have copied and pasted the whole code - if that is what you mean?

Comment: @Jems Your second comment helped!  When I went into R.layour.activity_main the editText id was showing as editTextTextName.  I amended this to editText only and now it is recognising it.  Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

**Try With This:**

```
val editText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText) as EditText
```

**Update**

```
const val EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE"

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val editText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText) as EditText
    val message = editText.text.toString()
}

/** Called when the user taps the Send button */
fun sendMessage(view: View) {
    val intent = Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity::class.java).apply {
        putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message)
    }
    startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the suggestion but it hasn't made a difference.  editText is still showing in red.

Comment: Please upload a picture of your typecasting error

Comment: I have updated the solution, try this now.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, this has now been resolved.

User Jems asked me to check the activity_main.xml to see if I had an id of editText.  I did but it had additional wording.  It was showing as editTextTextName, so I amended this to show only editText and now it is happy with the code.